# Create a row with sequence of nymbers based on column value

Tags: r

I have a dataset inwhich sequence of rows are related to one client. The end row of each client is "status OK". So, my data consists of blocks, each related to one client. I need to create a column to display the number of the client all over the block rows. For example my data is:

```
x = data.frame(A = c('name1', 'address1', 'status1', 'name2', 'address2', 'status2'), B= c('John', 'Texas', 'OK', 'William', 'Florida', 'OK')) x
```

My expected output is:

```
x = data.frame(A = c('name1', 'address1', 'status1', 'name2', 'address2', 'status2'), B = c('John', 'Texas', 'OK', 'William', 'Florida', 'OK'), C = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2')) x
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use this format? It seems really counter intuitive and would feel more intuitive with having 3 columns, `name address status`.

Comment: Actually I need the sequence column to organize the dataset. The only unique thing that identify blocks is "OK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` :

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% mutate(C = lag(cumsum(B == 'OK'), default = 0) + 1)

#         A       B C
#1    name1    John 1
#2 address1   Texas 1
#3  status1      OK 1
#4    name2 William 2
#5 address2 Florida 2
#6  status2      OK 2
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the 'client blocks' are not ordered, correct?

Comment: This increments when an 'OK' is encountered in column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract client ID:

```
x$C <- stringr::str_extract(x$A, "[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
x$C <- as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9]', "", x$A))
```